# Search a method in complete project

Tags: eclipse

How to Search A method in complete project,Though many classes may have method with same name can we get the list of all those methods.
I require a shortcut to search for those method in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to search any text throughout a workspace or project. To search method just give the metod name after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

With `Ctrl + H` you can search in ALL your project.